# Periodic background task in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Requests in my test plan use an authorization token that I know expires in 1 hour. I need somehow to re-request the token every 59 mins until the test finishes. Could someone please suggest the best method for that - looks like with While Controller the test would never finish staying in eternal while loop.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add another [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your test plan.
2. Configure it to run forever (or have enough loops to last long enough)
3. Add a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) to that second thread group. To make it fire each 59 minutes put `3540000` into "Thread Delay" input
4. Place your "token-obtaining" logic under the timer.
5. If your token is being stored as a property - main thread group will be able to use it. If it is a variable you'll need to convert it to a property so it [could be used across thread groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) as JMeter variables scope is limited to the current thread group only.

Hope this helps.