# Run certain ThreadGroup (or just an action) periodically

Tags: jmeter

I've got pretty similar problem as the one explained in [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427731/periodic-backgroud-task-in-jmeter).

The problem is that my TestPlan has got several Thread Groups, 
which are run consecutively (that is required).

Therefore, I cannot use the suggested solution of 'Add another Thread Group & Constant timer' as this would only work if I unchecked 'Run Thread Groups consecutively'.

***So, I need to trigger my 'Take_access_token' thread either every 30min or before every other Thread Group.*** 
[image]

I was thinking on applying some of the controllers:

Module or Interleave, but looks like they can apply only to the Sampler execution logic, and not the thread groups.

I'm sure jMeter has to have something. 
What am i missing?)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can I understand from this question is that you want to trigger your thread groups consecutively but before that `Take_acess_token` should generate some token which will be used by other thread groups.

So my suggestion to achieve this  requirement is shown in below snapshot
[image]

First apply token thread group with 1 user 1 iteration which will generate token and then save it to property to use it in another thread group then next thread group will perform some activity and once control will come out of this group it'll again enter into another thread group to generate token and similarly do this for other also

Hope this approach should help you!!

Comment: Right, but this way I'll have a numerous code duplication, and I really-really wanna avoid it :)

Comment: I accept, this way we'll have duplicacy of code but it will hit the Http requests only when required for token generation i.e. no extra hits on url. By the way, if you get any another solution then please share here also

Comment: @Yabko answer provided by TestingWithArif can work but I suspect there will be one issue that if you are running your thread groups with multiple iterations then it will hit the token generation requests multiple times (which is not required), so you can apply counter and if controller to execute the module controller only at first iteration

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable "Take Access Token" threadgroup
2. Add a simple controller under "Take Access Token" threadgroup
3. Move all the samplers to newly added Simple controller
4. Now you can add "Module Controller" in start of each of your thread group
5. Set path to your simple controller in these module controllers

This can solve your issue without any duplication of code.